# How to remove padding from TextButton and place it under widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Need help. I want to put the text `Want to get your money?` and TextButton `Redeem` under button `611` (screenshot below) removing all padding. I have already tried many methods, but in the end it did not work out to place the widget under the button itself. Through the Flutter Inspector, you can see that there is still a distance at the top, but I don’t understand how to put it there. I will be grateful for help.

**body**

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            const TotalCoinsWidget(
              coins: '611',
            ),
            const RedeemButton(
                textStyle: constants.Styles.smallBookTextStyleWhite,
                buttonStyle: constants.Styles.smallMediumTextStyleWhite),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
              child: Text('Hello'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
```

**textbutton**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('Want to get your money?', style: textStyle),
          TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              minimumSize: Size.zero,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              'Redeem',
              style: buttonStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
```

**TotalCoinsWidget**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: _width,
        height: _height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: color.withOpacity(0.5),
                blurRadius: _blurRadius,
                offset: Offset(_xOffset, _yOffset)),
          ],
        ),
        child: Text(
          coins,
          style: textStyle,
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Please share the whole code including the "611" container.

Comment: okey, I updated the code

Comment: Can you share the `TotalCoinsWidget` implementation ?

Comment: Updated the code, added earlier, just signed the code block incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `TextButton` widget, and if you check out the property `style: TextButton.styleFrom(),` you will find a property called `tapTargetSize`, by default `tapTargetSize` property uses `MaterialTapTargetSize.padded`, and to fix your problem you must assign `tapTargetSize` property to `MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` to shrinks the tap target size to the minimum size.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped. Tell me, can I remove paddings in all buttons or only in TextButton using this method?

Comment: i'm glad it helped, i think usually all buttons properties in flutter has very similar properties but i suggest every time you use a material/cupertino button (TextButton, IconButton...), to check all its properties and to try learn more about them!

Comment: It only shrinks it horizontally. Does not work for vertical shrink.

Comment: @MichałDobiDobrzański i suggest to check padding property (in TextButton.styleFrom) and set it to EdgeInsets.zero

Comment: also, you can check minimumSize property and set it to Size.zero

Answer (score 1):

```
tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap
```

is not sufficient. Just add

```
padding: EdgeInsets.zero
```

Comment: It only shrinks it horizontally. Does not work for vertical shrink.